# GW-Basic for Windows 7 (64 Bit)

Tags: windows-7-x64, gw-basic

I was looking GW-Basic for Windows 7 (64 Bit) but I could not find a compatible version.

After searching, I came to know about QBasic that would be used for GW-Basic programs.

Please help me set up the environment for GW-Basic.

Comment: The last version was retired 24 years ago.  You'll have to break into a museum.

Comment: First need to  Download DosBox and then GW-Basic. It will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [PC-BASIC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pcbasic/). It's a free implementation of GW-BASIC that runs natively on Windows 7 (as well as Linux and Mac).

Answer (score 4):

You may run old legacy (DOS) aplication like GW basic in emulator. The easiest way I think is using [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/). Some more complicated - is installing DOS on virtual machine like VMWare or VirualPC. There is also XPMode in Windows 7 which also may run DOS applications.